# Methods with different names vs single method with different enum params in java

Tags: java, methods

I have a use case where I need to call a similar logic, with different enum parameters. Although passing in the enum param gives good code reusability, some may argue that the other way of creating multiple functions with names denoting its operation gives good readability. Is there a strong opinion in programming community of choosing one over the other?

For eg.

```
enum e {
  aaa,
  bbb
};

foo(e enumParam) {
   // method impl using enumParam
}

Vs. 

fooAaa() {
  // method impl using enum e.AAA
}

fooBbb() {
  // method impl using enum e.BBB
}
```

Comment: Alternative: make `foo()` an instance method on `e`.

Comment: foo() uses other dependency objects and is a method of different class altogether.

Comment: One difference between the two approaches in the question is that you can only call `fooAaa()` and `fooBbb()` statically (in the sense that it's fixed at compile time), whereas with `foo(e)`, you can have an a-priori unknown instance of `e`. (Of course, you can use method references in Java 8+).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you must make a method that dispatches on the `enum`'s type because you cannot place the logic in an `enum`'s instance method, the first approach offers better code reuse in situations when the caller has an instance of `e` that comes from some other place.

Compare

```
void doSomething(e enumParam) {
    Foo.foo(enumParam);
}
```

vs.

```
void doSomething(e enumParam) {
    switch(enumParam) {
        case e.aaa: Foo.fooAaa(); break;
        case e.bbb: Foo.fooBbb(); break;
        default: ... // Throw some exception
    }
}
```

In the first case callers simply forward `enumParam` to `foo`. In the second case, however, callers need to dispatch on `e` themselves, repeatedly using similar logic to route the call to `fooAaa` vs. `fooBbb`.

Answer (score 1):

```
foo(e enumParam) {
   // method impl using enumParam
}
```

This is a better way. Enum can have big list, hence this single method can be used to accommodated additional enum properties. On the other hand if you use one method for one enum, you have to write number of methods equal to enum size.

Answer (score 0):

In the OOP world, method really represents the behavior or a character of a class. So if it really depends on whether fooAAA and fooBBB are different behaviors or one. If one, I would use the foo and decide alternate paths inside it ( could even be private methods ) for AAA and BBB.